# How to get the row values for every 30th minute?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataset, it's a dataframe:

```
    item    id  _value  agentstatus type    agenttimestamp  Unit    Calc1   Calc2
0   FCX.FCN2.PM01001_01_SUM.SUM 1   3   Good    Double  2022-01-01 09:00:00+00:00   kWh Diff    30min
1   FCX.FCN2.PM01002_01_SUM.SUM 2   3   Good    Double  2022-01-01 09:00:00+00:00   kWh Diff    30min
25  FCX.FCN2.PM01001_01_SUM.SUM 26  3   Good    Double  2022-01-01 09:10:00+00:00   kWh Diff    30min
26  FCX.FCN2.PM01002_01_SUM.SUM 27  3   Good    Double  2022-01-01 09:10:00+00:00   kWh Diff    30min
50  FCX.FCN2.PM01001_01_SUM.SUM 51  3   Good    Double  2022-01-01 09:20:00+00:00   kWh Diff    30min
51  FCX.FCN2.PM01002_01_SUM.SUM 52  3   Good    Double  2022-01-01 09:20:00+00:00   kWh Diff    30min
75  FCX.FCN2.PM01001_01_SUM.SUM 76  3   Good    Double  2022-01-01 09:30:00+00:00   kWh Diff    30min
76  FCX.FCN2.PM01002_01_SUM.SUM 77  3   Good    Double  2022-01-01 09:30:00+00:00   kWh Diff    30min
100 FCX.FCN2.PM01001_01_SUM.SUM 101 3   Good    Double  2022-01-01 09:40:00+00:00   kWh Diff    30min
101 FCX.FCN2.PM01002_01_SUM.SUM 102 3   Good    Double  2022-01-01 09:40:00+00:00   kWh Diff    30min
125 FCX.FCN2.PM01001_01_SUM.SUM 126 3   Good    Double  2022-01-01 09:50:00+00:00   kWh Diff    30min
126 FCX.FCN2.PM01002_01_SUM.SUM 127 3   Good    Double  2022-01-01 09:50:00+00:00   kWh Diff    30min
150 FCX.FCN2.PM01001_01_SUM.SUM 151 3   Good    Double  2022-01-01 10:00:00+00:00   kWh Diff    30min
151 FCX.FCN2.PM01002_01_SUM.SUM 152 3   Good    Double  2022-01-01 10:00:00+00:00   kWh Diff    30min
175 FCX.FCN2.PM01001_01_SUM.SUM 176 3   Good    Double  2022-01-01 10:10:00+00:00   kWh Diff    30min
176 FCX.FCN2.PM01002_01_SUM.SUM 177 3   Good    Double  2022-01-01 10:10:00+00:00   kWh Diff    30min
200 FCX.FCN2.PM01001_01_SUM.SUM 201 3   Good    Double  2022-01-01 10:20:00+00:00   kWh Diff    30min
201 FCX.FCN2.PM01002_01_SUM.SUM 202 3   Good    Double  2022-01-01 10:20:00+00:00   kWh Diff    30min
225 FCX.FCN2.PM01001_01_SUM.SUM 226 3   Good    Double  2022-01-01 10:30:00+00:00   kWh Diff    30min
226 FCX.FCN2.PM01002_01_SUM.SUM 227 3   Good    Double  2022-01-01 10:30:00+00:00   kWh Diff    30min
250 FCX.FCN2.PM01001_01_SUM.SUM 251 3   Good    Double  2022-01-01 10:40:00+00:00   kWh Diff    30min
251 FCX.FCN2.PM01002_01_SUM.SUM 252 3   Good    Double  2022-01-01 10:40:00+00:00   kWh Diff    30min
275 FCX.FCN2.PM01001_01_SUM.SUM 276 3   Good    Double  2022-01-01 10:50:00+00:00   kWh Diff    30min
276 FCX.FCN2.PM01002_01_SUM.SUM 277 3   Good    Double  2022-01-01 10:50:00+00:00   kWh Diff    30min
300 FCX.FCN2.PM01001_01_SUM.SUM 301 3   Good    Double  2022-01-01 11:00:00+00:00   kWh Diff    30min
301 FCX.FCN2.PM01002_01_SUM.SUM 302 3   Good    Double  2022-01-01 11:00:00+00:00   kWh Diff    30min
325 FCX.FCN2.PM01001_01_SUM.SUM 326 3   Good    Double  2022-01-01 11:10:00+00:00   kWh Diff    30min
326 FCX.FCN2.PM01002_01_SUM.SUM 327 3   Good    Double  2022-01-01 11:10:00+00:00   kWh Diff    30min
350 FCX.FCN2.PM01001_01_SUM.SUM 351 3   Good    Double  2022-01-01 11:20:00+00:00   kWh Diff    30min
351 FCX.FCN2.PM01002_01_SUM.SUM 352 3   Good    Double  2022-01-01 11:20:00+00:00   kWh Diff    30min
375 FCX.FCN2.PM01001_01_SUM.SUM 376 3   Good    Double  2022-01-01 11:30:00+00:00   kWh Diff    30min
376 FCX.FCN2.PM01002_01_SUM.SUM 377 3   Good    Double  2022-01-01 11:30:00+00:00   kWh Diff    30min
400 FCX.FCN2.PM01001_01_SUM.SUM 401 3   Good    Double  2022-01-01 11:40:00+00:00   kWh Diff    30min
401 FCX.FCN2.PM01002_01_SUM.SUM 402 3   Good    Double  2022-01-01 11:40:00+00:00   kWh Diff    30min
425 FCX.FCN2.PM01001_01_SUM.SUM 426 3   Good    Double  2022-01-01 11:50:00+00:00   kWh Diff    30min
426 FCX.FCN2.PM01002_01_SUM.SUM 427 3   Good    Double  2022-01-01 11:50:00+00:00   kWh Diff    30min
450 FCX.FCN2.PM01001_01_SUM.SUM 451 3   Good    Double  2022-01-01 12:00:00+00:00   kWh Diff    30min
451 FCX.FCN2.PM01002_01_SUM.SUM 452 3   Good    Double  2022-01-01 12:00:00+00:00   kWh Diff    30min
475 FCX.FCN2.PM01001_01_SUM.SUM 476 3   Good    Double  2022-01-01 12:10:00+00:00   kWh Diff    30min
476 FCX.FCN2.PM01002_01_SUM.SUM 477 3   Good    Double  2022-01-01 12:10:00+00:00   kWh Diff    30min
500 FCX.FCN2.PM01001_01_SUM.SUM 501 3   Good    Double  2022-01-01 12:20:00+00:00   kWh Diff    30min
501 FCX.FCN2.PM01002_01_SUM.SUM 502 3   Good    Double  2022-01-01 12:20:00+00:00   kWh Diff    30min
525 FCX.FCN2.PM01001_01_SUM.SUM 526 3   Good    Double  2022-01-01 12:30:00+00:00   kWh Diff    30min
526 FCX.FCN2.PM01002_01_SUM.SUM 527 3   Good    Double  2022-01-01 12:30:00+00:00   kWh Diff    30min
550 FCX.FCN2.PM01001_01_SUM.SUM 551 3   Good    Double  2022-01-01 12:40:00+00:00   kWh Diff    30min
551 FCX.FCN2.PM01002_01_SUM.SUM 552 3   Good    Double  2022-01-01 12:40:00+00:00   kWh Diff    30min
575 FCX.FCN2.PM01001_01_SUM.SUM 576 3   Good    Double  2022-01-01 12:50:00+00:00   kWh Diff    30min
576 FCX.FCN2.PM01002_01_SUM.SUM 577 3   Good    Double  2022-01-01 12:50:00+00:00   kWh Diff    30min
600 FCX.FCN2.PM01001_01_SUM.SUM 601 3   Good    Double  2022-01-01 13:00:00+00:00   kWh Diff    30min
601 FCX.FCN2.PM01002_01_SUM.SUM 602 3   Good    Double  2022-01-01 13:00:00+00:00   kWh Diff    30min
```

**Expected output**

```
    item    id  _value  agentstatus type    agenttimestamp  Unit    Calc1   Calc2
75  FCX.FCN2.PM01001_01_SUM.SUM 76  3   Good    Double  2022-01-01 09:30:00+00:00   kWh Diff    30min
76  FCX.FCN2.PM01002_01_SUM.SUM 77  3   Good    Double  2022-01-01 09:30:00+00:00   kWh Diff    30min
150 FCX.FCN2.PM01001_01_SUM.SUM 151 3   Good    Double  2022-01-01 10:00:00+00:00   kWh Diff    30min
151 FCX.FCN2.PM01002_01_SUM.SUM 152 3   Good    Double  2022-01-01 10:00:00+00:00   kWh Diff    30min
225 FCX.FCN2.PM01001_01_SUM.SUM 226 3   Good    Double  2022-01-01 10:30:00+00:00   kWh Diff    30min
226 FCX.FCN2.PM01002_01_SUM.SUM 227 3   Good    Double  2022-01-01 10:30:00+00:00   kWh Diff    30min
300 FCX.FCN2.PM01001_01_SUM.SUM 301 3   Good    Double  2022-01-01 11:00:00+00:00   kWh Diff    30min
301 FCX.FCN2.PM01002_01_SUM.SUM 302 3   Good    Double  2022-01-01 11:00:00+00:00   kWh Diff    30min
375 FCX.FCN2.PM01001_01_SUM.SUM 376 3   Good    Double  2022-01-01 11:30:00+00:00   kWh Diff    30min
376 FCX.FCN2.PM01002_01_SUM.SUM 377 3   Good    Double  2022-01-01 11:30:00+00:00   kWh Diff    30min
450 FCX.FCN2.PM01001_01_SUM.SUM 451 3   Good    Double  2022-01-01 12:00:00+00:00   kWh Diff    30min
451 FCX.FCN2.PM01002_01_SUM.SUM 452 3   Good    Double  2022-01-01 12:00:00+00:00   kWh Diff    30min
525 FCX.FCN2.PM01001_01_SUM.SUM 526 3   Good    Double  2022-01-01 12:30:00+00:00   kWh Diff    30min
526 FCX.FCN2.PM01002_01_SUM.SUM 527 3   Good    Double  2022-01-01 12:30:00+00:00   kWh Diff    30min
600 FCX.FCN2.PM01001_01_SUM.SUM 601 3   Good    Double  2022-01-01 13:00:00+00:00   kWh Diff    30min
601 FCX.FCN2.PM01002_01_SUM.SUM 602 3   Good    Double  2022-01-01 13:00:00+00:00   kWh Diff    30min
```

What I tried and the actual output:

I tried with df.resample('30T', on='agenttimestamp') but it isn't working or the output isn't giving the results as expected, the output is same as the input when I apply resample.

Please let me know how to do this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about `df[df['agenttimestamp'].dt.minute % 30 == 0]`?

```
from io import StringIO
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv(StringIO(
"""agenttimestamp
'2022-01-01 09:00:00+00:00'
'2022-01-01 09:00:00+00:00'
'2022-01-01 09:10:00+00:00'
'2022-01-01 09:10:00+00:00'
'2022-01-01 09:20:00+00:00'
'2022-01-01 09:20:00+00:00'
'2022-01-01 09:30:00+00:00'
'2022-01-01 09:30:00+00:00'
'2022-01-01 09:40:00+00:00'
'2022-01-01 09:40:00+00:00'
'2022-01-01 09:50:00+00:00'
'2022-01-01 09:50:00+00:00'
'2022-01-01 10:00:00+00:00'
'2022-01-01 10:00:00+00:00'
'2022-01-01 10:10:00+00:00'
'2022-01-01 10:10:00+00:00'
'2022-01-01 10:20:00+00:00'
'2022-01-01 10:20:00+00:00'
'2022-01-01 10:30:00+00:00'
'2022-01-01 10:30:00+00:00'
'2022-01-01 10:40:00+00:00'
'2022-01-01 10:40:00+00:00'
'2022-01-01 10:50:00+00:00'
'2022-01-01 10:50:00+00:00'
'2022-01-01 11:00:00+00:00'
'2022-01-01 11:00:00+00:00'
'2022-01-01 11:10:00+00:00'
'2022-01-01 11:10:00+00:00'
'2022-01-01 11:20:00+00:00'
'2022-01-01 11:20:00+00:00'
'2022-01-01 11:30:00+00:00'
'2022-01-01 11:30:00+00:00'
'2022-01-01 11:40:00+00:00'
'2022-01-01 11:40:00+00:00'
'2022-01-01 11:50:00+00:00'
'2022-01-01 11:50:00+00:00'
'2022-01-01 12:00:00+00:00'
'2022-01-01 12:00:00+00:00'
'2022-01-01 12:10:00+00:00'
'2022-01-01 12:10:00+00:00'
'2022-01-01 12:20:00+00:00'
'2022-01-01 12:20:00+00:00'
'2022-01-01 12:30:00+00:00'
'2022-01-01 12:30:00+00:00'
'2022-01-01 12:40:00+00:00'
'2022-01-01 12:40:00+00:00'
'2022-01-01 12:50:00+00:00'
'2022-01-01 12:50:00+00:00'
'2022-01-01 13:00:00+00:00'
'2022-01-01 13:00:00+00:00'"""), parse_dates=['agenttimestamp'])

df[df['agenttimestamp'].dt.minute % 30 == 0]

# Output:
0  2022-01-01 09:00:00+00:00
1  2022-01-01 09:00:00+00:00
6  2022-01-01 09:30:00+00:00
7  2022-01-01 09:30:00+00:00
12 2022-01-01 10:00:00+00:00
13 2022-01-01 10:00:00+00:00
18 2022-01-01 10:30:00+00:00
19 2022-01-01 10:30:00+00:00
24 2022-01-01 11:00:00+00:00
25 2022-01-01 11:00:00+00:00
30 2022-01-01 11:30:00+00:00
31 2022-01-01 11:30:00+00:00
36 2022-01-01 12:00:00+00:00
37 2022-01-01 12:00:00+00:00
42 2022-01-01 12:30:00+00:00
43 2022-01-01 12:30:00+00:00
48 2022-01-01 13:00:00+00:00
49 2022-01-01 13:00:00+00:00
```

Update: to remove the first timestamp, assuming the first timestamp appears twice, you can use `iloc`:

```
df[df['agenttimestamp'].dt.minute % 30 == 0].iloc[2:]
```

Comment: Thanks Mark..but I don't need the first value, as in 9:00:00. Basically I wish to take the difference between 9:30:00 - 9:00:00 and want to retain only the 9:30:00 timestamp row values.

Comment: Hi Nishad, I don't know if I follow. Can you rephrase it

Comment: you said you wanted every 30th minute, and that's what I gave you. If the criteria is different, please spell out what it is for me please :-) I have no clue

Comment: are you specifically wanting to exclude 9 am and only 9 am? or is it just the first row, regardless?

Comment: Sorry if I was misleading. I had given the expected output, in that the first timestamp which is 9:00:00 is eliminated and then every other 30th min value.. your logic is correct but also how to eliminate the first timestamp, because that's the starting of the dataset in the file.

Comment: Not specifically 9AM. The dataset is generated at 3:00:00, 6:00:00, 9:00:00 and 12:00:00. So every file has that timestamp as the first value which I want to eliminate.. I'll explain if it's not clear again.

Comment: Assuming the first value appears twice, you can use df.iloc[2:]. See my update :-)

Comment: This looks good.. Actually not twice. The first value is there for every item value. If you see there are two names in item PM01001 and PM01002, So is it possible to include or consider to remove that first value for every 'item' ? That is why I had mentioned all the rows required in the expected output, every value in the expected output is to be considered. I'm sure the output is almost there. Could you consider just these also please

Comment: Instead of just the timestamp column. Could you consider all the columns, as in the expected output. :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/254886/discussion-between-mark-and-nishad-nazar).

Comment: If you can add the dict or json version of the dataframe, I'd be happy to!